# load balancing using weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

Currently, I am in designing phase of my project which will require load balancing.

The application will be a batch app running throughout the day and polling for some files dropped in a shared location.

Once it gets a file it has to pass that file to one of the servers, depending on which is free (files are time bound, so they have to be processed as soon as possible).

And for some reason, we have to stick to Weblogic only.

Now for this purpose can I use weblogic's inbuilt feature of load balancing ??
I am confused on how exactly will this load balancing work, because in case of a web application it will pass on the request to one of the servers based on the algorithm. But in my case it is not a web application but a Java program.

Please help me with this, I mean where to start from.

I was able to create HTTP clusters on weblogic, but how will i use these clusters in my application i have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zack,

You could have this batch application (which I imagine would be a plain Java application for your description) pooling for those files in that shared location, once it finds something you can have it **invoke a EJB or RMI Object that is load balanced on your X instances of Weblogic**, or even populate a JMS queue to process this file for you (in a clustered environment)

It's not at all something unusual to do with Weblogic's clustering features, and you use different load balancing algorithms (such as **round-robin, weight-based and random**)

There are different ways to set it up depending on your approach and preferred algorithm, check out [Weblogic Load Balancing documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/cluster/load_balancing.html#wp1008605) and this section of [Weblogic Definitive Guide Book - Using JNDI in a Clustered Environment](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/weblogic/059600432x/using-jndi-and-rmi/weblogictdg-chp-4-sect-2)